# In-line retag doesn't result in last editor being updated

Tags: bug, inline-tag-editor

If I do a retag using in-line tagging, then the last editor for the post doesn't get updated.

[image]

For instance:

Now, once I complete the retag, the editor name isn't updated.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe clicking the grey bar to load new edits will refresh the "edited by" part either.

Answer (score 1):

The "edited by" field isn't dynamically changed, it is set when the page is loaded. Simply reload the page and it will reflect the change.

I believe [this is the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139349/167443) you retagged.

Comment: Hence "bug", because one would expect that information to refresh, since the page now knows about it. Most likely that needs to be built into the API, then it can be requeried and reloaded.